# How to deal with form size issues from Delphi 6 and WinXP to Delphi 2007 and Vista/Win7

Tags: windows, delphi, forms, size, border

I have an application written in Delphi 6 and compiled on Windows XP. Usually I leave 8px free between controls and the edges of forms.

When this app runs on Vista or Win 7 this gap is smaller or not present at all. I think this might be because these versions of Windows have thicker form borders.

Now I am moving the app to Delphi 2007. In the form designer the forms have lost the bottom and right gaps.

How should I deal with this? I have hundreds of forms and don't want to go changing them all. Also, most of our users run the app on Win XP so I don't want to make it look bad in XP.

Comment: there's something else you aren't telling us. I've recently ported from d6 to d2010 and had no such trouble

Comment: Are you or have you tried using a Manifest? Maybe you could specify XP Compatibility mode?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "something wicked this way comes".
Just hit the wall, that TForm.ClientWidth returns a totally crazy result on Win8.x regardless of DPI ....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short version: change all form's to `AutoScroll = False`

---

The problem is the form's `AutoScroll` property, and how it affects which form size is stored in the DFM.

If `AutoScroll` is **true** (the default) the DFM will store `Width` and `Height`:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 192
  Top = 114
  Width = 544
  Height = 375
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ...
```

If `AutoScroll` is **false** (the *preferred* setting) the DFM will store `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight`:

```
object frmSplash: TfrmSplash
  Left = 192
  Top = 114
  ClientWidth = 536
  ClientHeight = 348
  Caption = 'Form1'
```

The problem with storing `Height` is what happens when the user's *caption bar* is a different size than your development machine, e.g.

- you develop on Windows 2000, program runs on Windows XP
- you develop on Windows XP, program runs on Windows Vista
- you develop with small fonts, program runs with large fonts

Windows 2000 had a 4 pixel border, with a 23 pixel caption bar. With the DFM storing a `Height` of 375, this leaves 348px for form client area.

Run the same program on Windows XP, which has a taller (28 pixel) caption bar. With the DFM storing a `Height` of 375 pixels, this leaves 343px for client area.

Your form "got 5 pixels shorter".

You need to force Delphi to store the `ClientWidth` and `ClientHeight` in the DFM by turning `AutoScroll` off.

Now when you create your 348px tall form on Windows XP, it will continue to have 348 pixels in the client area - and be however extra tall is required to have a caption bar.

i go so far as to have an `OutputDebugString` and a breakpoint trigger if my helper library code finds any form that mistakenly has `AutoScroll` set to **true**.

---

**Edit:** Since i try to be a good developer, i make my form's respect the user's font preference. During the `OnCreate` of all my forms i call a `StandardizeForm(Self)` function that:

- scales the form to match the user's default font size
- changes the font on all controls on the form to the user's preference
- issues an ODS if the form is set mistakenly set to `Scaled`
- **issues an ODS and breakpoint if `AutoScroll` true (and sets it to false)**
- issues an ODS and breakpoint if `ShowHint` is false (and turns it on)
- etc

You can do something similar. Yes you'd have to add:

```
procedure TCustomerEditForm.FormCreat(Sender: TObject);
begin
   StandardizeForm(Self); //Pay your taxes!
   ...
end;
```

But it's worth it for me.

Comment: Also, why don't you have your own tax-free form class?

Comment: @cja: There's little value gained by forcing everyone to install a new design-time package. This way is ***much*** easier.

Comment: @IanBoyd You can make a class available to your project without installing a new design time package

Comment: there is an opensourced project, that i did not find time to review though. Maybe ut would make sense for you to review it and perhaps join efforts. See https://github.com/delphinotes/BaseForms.git